# How to load HTML through AJAX the RJS way using jQuery and UJS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3 with Ruby 1.9.2.

I'm following an article on using RJS in Ruby on Rails 2.x. Since then the Rails developers  removed the Prototype dependency of Rails, however, by doing so they removed the RJS functionality and `link_to_remote` with it as well. Now we're supposed to use `link_to` with `:remote => true` as an argument, but it has fewer features for doing remote stuff the easy way compared to  `link_to_remote` and `render(:update)` in Rails 2.x.

I set up [jQuery for UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

What's the best way to fetch HTML remotely through AJAX and render it inside of a div tag? I want to  do that using similar features as the old RJS, using `render(:update)`.

I hope I don't have to bind jQuery events by hand to be able to load HTML remotely into the DOM since the RJS features seemed so nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually call partials from my js.erb file:

```
$('#container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'content')) %>");
```

And the proper html I want in the partial.

It may not make sense for you if you have few html. In this case, write it directly in your js.erb file.

You could have a look at this short tutorial: http://blog.bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/

Comment: I'm very new to Ruby on Rails, but what confuses me about the tutorial is that the logic relies on the user "clicking" on a link/button/action within a form. How does this answer the question, perhaps not implied by @Kristinn, of dynamically loading the content "automatically," into a div **without** the use of a form?  In other words, conceptually or literally, what am I missing that Kristinn obviously new, to apply this to his project?  Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @Rick. I don't understand your question. Can you explain it in more details to me? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kristinn! Sorry for the confusion. I actually clarified and asked it here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303595/ruby-on-rails-running-twitter-gem-after-page-loads/)

Comment: Hi @Rick. Hehe not a problem. Glad you got a solution. :-)

Comment: The link is broken. Rather than only point to an off-site page, you should summarize the information that is important also. That way, if the link rots and breaks the important information remains in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use RJS (Rails 3 still has RJS) but I prefer writing directly to js.erb files as well.

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html 'id_of_dom_obj', :partial => 'partial_path'
end
```

Comment: This tries to find a view "update" to render in Rails 3, giving a missing template error.

Comment: add `gem "prototype-rails"` to the Gemfile and `render :update` will work again