# How to run Twitter gem after page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter

I am using a [Twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/), however I was hoping to understand how to run it in the background after the page loads.

Currently I  need to wait for the page to render, since the  gem is working to query some tweets.  Once the  gem gets its response, the page loads.

However, I was hoping to display a "loading" GIF in my Twitter feed "div" tag, and once the Twitter information is retrieved, replace this GIF with the respective content.

I read several posts how to use a form and the "`:remote => true`" tag on the form in order to do AJAX calls that won't reload the respective page, but I don't want to force visitors to click a link in order to see Twitter tweets.

I'm using:

- Ruby version: 1.8.7
- Rails version: 3.0.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this; A fairly common practice and the way I would go about this is to use the the jQuery's `$.ajax()` to get data from the server and update the page.

Client-side:

1. Load the page normally and show some kind of loading indicator.
2. Make a call to `$.ajax()`:

   ```
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: userId + '/tweets', // i.e. tweets is a nested resource of user
     success: function(tweets){
       $('#loading_indicator').hide();

       // Use the tweets that are returned to update the DOM
       $.each(tweets, function(ndx, tweet) {
         $('#tweet_list').append('<li>'+tweet.body+<'/li'>);
       });
     }
   });
   ```

Server-side:

Have an action in a controller that sends out tweets as JSON to be consumed by the client-side *success* callback. Setup the routing for this action to be compatible with *url* in `$.ajax()`:

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    # collect tweets...
    render :json => @tweets
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Like I mentioned in the description, I'm really green to RoR.  What would call the controller's "show" logic?  Also, do I put the client-side AJAX code in the application.js file?  Aside from implementing all of this, I'm trying to connect the proverbial dots, between the client and server code.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Would the "URL" portion of the AJAX call point and activate the "show" method in the controller, i.e. the routes.rb file would contain a "match" from user/tweets => tweets#show?

Comment: 'show' corresponds to a GET action if you are using _RESTful_ routing, _[See routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)_. The _URL_ portion of the AJAX can point to anything as long as you have a route setup that responds to it. Run `rake routes` for a list of routes your application uses or use `curl [URL]` to see what is returned from a URL.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful feedback!  However, I think I'm stuck. I note in my logs how the controller's method is being called, "show" in your example, but the "success" settings logic in the AJAX function is never called.  As a test, I added the line "alert('I'm in the AJAX call');" just after the "success" settings "open bracket," before the "$('#loading_indicator').hide();" line, and an alert box did not appear. I made sure that the function being called by the AJAX call is returning "render :json => @tweets" and @tweets is simply being assigned a string, for testing purposes.

Comment: In an effort to debug further, I added an error function to the AJAX call.  It seems that I'm getting a "parseError," where the reason is "Unexpected token ILLEGAL."  How can I troubleshoot this?  As I mentioned earlier, my method is simply assigning a "string" to the "@tweets" variable, before the line "render :json => @tweets"

Comment: I also looked at the "responseText," via the jqXHR object, and it contains the single word I sent via JSON. I can't understand what the "unexpected" and "illegal" token is.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by using this line in the return of my respective "show" method: 'render :text => tweets.to_json'  I don't know why this would work over 'render :json => tweets', but I'm assuming it has something to do with the response header information that Rails sends back to JQuery's AJAX call?